# Replace words marked with offsets

Tags: string, numpy, replace, nltk

I have a sentence like that:

"*My name is Bond. It's a fake name.*"

and I have to replace some words in a list with offsets of each word:

**name, 29-33; Bond, 11-15; name, 3-7**

In addition, each word must replace with a specific word:

**name -> noun**

**Bond -> proper**

I have to obtain this output:

"*My **noun** is **proper**. It's a fake **noun**.*"

I tried to manage the offsets with a post-offset variable that I update after each replacement but it is not valid because is an unordered list. Note that find method is not valid due to *name*s repetition. Is there any algorithm to do it? Any vectorial implementation (String, Numpy, NLTK) that computes it in one step?

Comment: Yes, this is an easy one. First create an index of words (i.e. your vocabulary). Then substitute all words with numbers. Now go through your list of words you want to change to NN/NNP, then replace them.

Comment: Creating a vocabulary appears to be fixed. Imagine that I have a sentence where **name** would be a **proper** noun as: "*My business is called NAME*", it would be changed by **noun**.

Comment: I have never seen such a thing as an "unordered list" in Python. Can you show some code? As you seem to have a partially working soluction already...

Answer (score 0):

Bro Check this one :

`string = "My name is Bond. It's a fake name."`

`y=list()`

`y=string.split(" ") #now it will break your strings into words`

Now traverse the list and set the condition

`for i in y:`

```
     if(i==name):
           i="noun"
     if(i==Bond):
           i="Proper"
```

Now the list values will be changed and use the Join() method to make back the list into string
For more Please refer to this website https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_strings.htm

This page contains all the data related to string processing in python.

Comment: That is not a good solution bro! Imagine that I have a multi-word name as James Bond, I couldn't do the split. That's why I have to use the offsets.

Comment: Okay , But i am also a newbie hence i tell you like this way  :-)

Comment: No problem :). Thanks for your contribution.